# Detect .NET 4.5.1 and future backwards-compatible releases

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

Per the guidance laid out in the MSDN article [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx#net_b) I have coded a WiX installer to check the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Release` registry key to determine that .NET 4.5.1 is installed, and use that detection to set a prerequisite.

The problem I've run into now, is when .NET 4.5.2 is installed, that same key is no longer `378675` or `378758`, but is now `379893`. .NET 4.5.2 is supposed to be a "highly compatible, in-place update", yet the recommended version-checking algorithm is not backwards-compatible.

Checks for prior versions didn't have this issue, the 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 registry keys are all still present even if a later version is installed. e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Version` is still present even if 3.5 is installed.

So previously, the Microsoft-recommended version detection method was forwards-compatible, but that's no longer the case with 4.5 / 4.5.1 / 4.5.2. What then, should I be doing instead? I'm loathe to just add `379893` (.NET 4.5.2) to the set of registry values I check for, since that will presumably fail when (if) .NET 4.5.3 (or other) is released. Maybe I could check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Version` for >= 4.5.51641, but that's **not** the recommended approach according to MSDN, and what happens if they release, say, 4.6 which is somehow *not* backwards-compatible?

Comment: i would assume that a not compatible release would no longer set its version key under v4.

Comment: Microsoft no longer wants you to do this, so they made it as difficult as possible.  .NET programs know how to install the framework version they need by themselves, you are not supposed to help.

Answer (score 1):

[To find .NET Framework versions by querying the registry in code (.NET Framework 4.5 and later)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx#net_d) states:

> Check the value of the Release keyword to determine the installed version. To be forward-compatible, you can check for a value greater than or equal to the values listed in the table.

That was just slightly below where the MSDN link in the original question pointed (thanks for getting me close).

In my .wxs file, I have code that appears to work, failing with a valid message on too-low .Net 4.5 version.

Place the following property reference and condition in <Product>:

```
<!-- Must have at least .Net 4.5.2 which has release 379893 -->
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45RELEASE"/>
<Condition Message="$(var.ProductName) requires .NET Framwork 4.5.2. Please install the .NET Framwork then run this installer again.">
    Installed OR ( NETFRAMEWORK45RELEASE AND NETFRAMEWORK45RELEASE >= "#379893" )
</Condition>
```

With the following fragment declared elsewhere:

```
<Fragment>
    <Property Id="NETFRAMEWORK45RELEASE">
        <RegistrySearch Id="NetFramework452Release"
                        Root="HKLM"
                        Key="Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                        Name="Release"
                        Type="raw" />
    </Property>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why you would worry about a future version not being backward compatible, they've all been so far and there's no reason to believe that would change. You're creating your installer today, not whenever 4.6 is released, so even if you could detect that, what exactly would you do? Refuse to install while it most likely be compatible? There is nothing to detect except to make sure a .net version of [at least whatever you target] is installed.

Also if you're really worried about a future major version breaking compatibility, you could embed the installer for the version of .net you target, if it so happens than your application gets installed on say Windows 9 / .net 6 later and those happen to not be in place upgrades, the installer would install the previous version side by side and when multiple .net versions are installed side by side the one that matches your appliaction will be used.

Comment: Not all .NET versions have been backwards compatible. If I had an application targeting 2.0 for example and ran a check for "greater than 2.0", my application would fail on a PC that **only** has .NET 4.0 installed. .NET 4.0 > 2.0, but does not include the 2.0 runtime.

Comment: Embedding an installer will not work, it is not possible to install .NET 4.5.1 over the top of .NET 4.5.2 for example. If my application forced the uninstall of 4.5.2 in favour of 4.5.1, it would potentially break other applications depending on 4.5.2.

Comment: @Snixtor no but if 4.5.2 is installed the installer would simply fail (this is fine due to backward compatibility) however if some hypotetical 5.0 was installed, didn't include 4 and didnt include the 4 runtime, the install would suceed, so it actually does work here (in your 2.0 example, embeding the 2.0 installer and running it in all cases is a solution, if 3 was installed, it would get skipped, if 4 was installed, it would get installed, sounds like it does solve your issue no?)

Comment: "if 4.5.2 is installed the installer would simply fail" - But this is just the original problem again. If 4.5.2 is installed, my installer needs to **not** fail, because 4.5.2 is backwards compatible with 4.5.1. As I've said, I *could* have my installer check the regkey for >= 4.5.51641. But that's not an MS recommended method, and is basically reverse-engineering. I'm looking for evidence of that being a suitable option, rather than guess-work.

Comment: @Snixtor No i mean the .net 4.5.1 installer would fail, don't mark it as a prerequisite, just run the installer in silent mode, if it fails then all is fine and if it works, well all is fine too! And in all case continue with your program insaller regardless of if .net install failed (higher version already installed) or if it succeeded (side by side version or no version and install succeeded)

Comment: But then the installer would succeed if .NET install failed for **any** reason. That's not a robust solution.

Comment: That's true but i think you're taking it a bit too much at heart to manage the end user pc which isn't your business as the application maker, indicate your application requires .net version X, on top of it try to install it anyway to make sure, if it still fails then what can you be expected to do as a .net application maker on a pc on which .net won't install? I know it doesn't feel robust, but to me it does feel like a reasonable tradeoff.

Comment: I found the text "Check the value of the Release keyword to determine the installed version. To be forward-compatible, you can check for a value greater than or equal to the values listed in the table" on the MSDN page in the question. I think that solves the problem.